# Win Server 2019 Hypervisor, VMs show high ram usage, Hypervisor doesnt?

Tags: windows, memory-usage

Im having a really weird issue with my server, never had it before.

Hypervisor is running Win 2019, VMs are mixed 2012r2 and win 10. Im running about 10 VMs on 128gb ram, vms inside show ~90% ram usage but when i open task manager total memory usage for each running program only adds up to about 40% of VM ram usage.

In the hypervisor it shows the expected ram usage for each VM, not the 90% ram usage. So in HV it says VM#1 is using 8gb of ram when task manager inside VM1 says its using 17gb of ram, while programs inside that VM dont add up to that much ram usage.

This inflated memory usage appears in most or all VMs, but when i check in Hypervisor Hyper-V window, each VM shows the expected ram usage and not inflated numbers. Any idea whats going on?

Weird thing is when i reboot the VM, it shows expected mem usage at startup but then fills up to 90% after 1-2min.

I read a similar thread about VMWare memory allocation, was something about setting memory allocation in hypervisor so it doesnt panic and think its running out of ram and tricks the VMs that theyre about to run out of ram to have them use less memory. Sounds like it might be something like that going on here? Though Hypervisor is totally fine memory wise, has 70gb free.

Hypervisor:
[Hypervisor memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k14fw.png)

VM:
[VM memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtZ1k.png)

[VM Total program memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0baS.png)